# How to keep my Python build results open while searching in Sublime Text 3

Tags: logging, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there a way to keep the build results showing while I search for things in the file I just ran. I get logging messages sent to the build results and use it to trace errors. However when I search for a term from the log output the build result gets hidden. Currently my workaround is to bind the build result view to `alt+b`:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+b"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec", "toggle": true} }
```

Still, this is a workaround. I'd like the output to just sit there while I work on the bug. Sending it to a different window would work to. I got plenty of screen real estate.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the way Sublime is designed you can only have one panel open at a time. What this means in practicality is that you can't, for example, search in build results without copying the results to a new tab, and that is the workaround I'd suggest to you. It's manual, and hacky, but you should be able to pull together a macro to do it (hopefully). I'm sorry nothing better is available, but this is the result of a design decision made by the author. Just hope for the source opening some day! :)